# fsockopen & Close connection in PHP but keep executing script

Tags: php, http, soap, http-headers, buffer

I've a PHP script that need Close connection after return data, but continue executing:

```
<?php
  // Some code

  ob_start();

  echo $data;

  header("Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n");
  header("Content-Length: " . ob_get_length() . "\r\n");
  header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
  header("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

  // Print buffer
  ob_end_flush();
  ob_flush();
  flush();

  // Close connection

  // Some code, continue executing
?>
```

It's work with some clients, but I need to call sometimes with an other PHP script

```
<?php
    // Some code

    $connection = @fsockopen($url['host'], $url['port'], $errno, $errstr);

    if (!$connection) { 
      throw new Exception('');
    }

    fputs($connection, "POST {$url['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($connection, "Host: {$url['host']}\r\n");
    fputs($connection, "Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n");
    fputs($connection, "SOAPAction: \"{$soapaction}\"\r\n");
    fputs($connection, "Content-Length: " . strlen($request) . "\r\n");
    fputs($connection, "Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
    fputs($connection, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    fputs($connection, $request);

    $respponse = '';
    while(!feof($connection)) {
      // receive the results of the request
      $response .= fgets($connection, 512);
    }

    // some code
?>
```

The problem is: fsockopen doesn't close connection when receive the data, only when all first scripts ends.

The only idea I have, it is check the length and close manual when the data is received.

Answer (score 0):

Your first (server) script will keep the socket open untill it terminates.
Sockets are lower level then HTTP and when you send Connection: close header you second (client) script is supposed to handle it itself rather then fsockopen function.

Doing what you do (counting number of bytes in response) is the right way to deal with it.